# Struggeling to send .jpg via requests library and store it correctly in database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, python-requests, flask-sqlalchemy

Im building an app with pythons flask. For one function in want to send a jpg to the app. after receiving the image my app commits it to the database using sqlalchemy.
for sending the image I read it in binary and add it to a dictionary which gets send with the requests library, like you can see in the following code.

```
import requests
from icecream import ic

# Specify the URL you want to send the request to
url = "http://127.0.0.1:4000/API/visual-check"  # Replace with your actual URL

# Create a dictionary containing the data to send in the request
data = {
    "drill_ID": 2,
    "screw_number": "6",
    "delta_time": 0.5,
    "accuracy": "0.798"
}
ic(data)
image_path = "visual-check-for-screw-2.jpg"

with open("visual-check-for-screw-2.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    # Include the image in the request as a file
    data["image"] = image_file.read()
ic(type(data["image"]))
# Send the POST request with the data and the image
response = requests.post(url, data=data)

# Check the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Request was successful.")
else:
    print("Request failed with status code:", response.status_code)
```

The flask app receives the request and stores it in the database using following code.

```
@requests.route("/visual-check", methods=["POST"])
def visual_check(): 
       
    data = request.form
    # image arrives as string. so i try to convert it back to binary
    image = bytes(data["image"], "utf-8")
    
    # Adding Request to Database
    current_request = PerformanceCheckRequest()
    current_request.image = image
    current_request.classification_result = data["screw_number"]
    current_request.accuracy = data["accuracy"]
    current_request.delta_time = data["delta_time"]
    db.session.add(current_request)
    db.session.commit()
```

When I load the image into the database i try to review it. therefor i use a database browser for sqlite. the image data gets stored but no displayed correctly.
for example in another part of my app i upload a image using following code:

```
image_path = 'website/static/machine-images\WashingMachine_bgUI.jpg'
with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    image_data = image_file.read()
    machine = Machine(name=machine, image=image_data)
    machine.screw_layout = json.dumps(screw_layout)
    db.session.add(machine)
    db.session.commit()
```

there i can review the image:
[correct Image review in database browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aycWJ.png)

I if try the same with my current code the image data seems to get stored but the image doesnt get displayed in the database browser which gives me the feeling like something before goes wrong.
[failed Image review in database browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSgGm.png)

my guess is that something goes south when the data gets converted from binary to string and back. but i have no idea, what. im really grateful for any help, hint or suggestions.
Thanks everbody!

Comment: At a guess, the sending code in url-encoding the image, so decoding on the server gets you the urlencoded string as bytes, not the original image.  It's more common to send  image bytes as base64-encoded strings.